# Cumulative DQL with Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine, sum, dql

Im having a hard time working out a proper DQL to generate cumulative sum. I can do it in plain SQL but when it comes to DQL i cant get hold of it.

Here is how it looks in SQL:

```
    SELECT s.name, p.date_short, p.nettobuy,
    (select sum(pp.nettobuy) as sum from price pp where pp.stock_id = p.stock_id and p.broker_id = pp.broker_id and pp.date_short <= p.date_short) as cumulative_sum
FROM price p
    left join stock s on p.stock_id = s.id
    group by p.stock_id, p.date_short
    order by p.stock_id, p.date_short
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Hey, I have check the documentation for Doctrine 1.2, and the way to create the query is (put attention on the alias):

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create();
$query->addSelect('AVG(price) as price');
$query->addSelect('AVG(cost) as cost');
// as many addSelect() as you need
$query->from('my_table');
```

To output the SQL query created:

```
echo $query->getSqlQuery();
```

To execute the statement:

```
$product = $query->fetchOne();
```

And to access the retrieved data is:

```
echo $product->getPrice();
echo $product->getCost();
```

Read the rest of the documentation at [Group By Clauses](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_2/en/dql-doctrine-query-language%3Agroup-by,-having-clauses).

Answer (score 2):

You just specify the sum in your select part of the DQL:

```
$query = Doctrine_Query::create()
   ->select('sum(amount)')
   ->from('some_table');
```

Check out [this page](http://www.doctrine-project.org/documentation/manual/1_1/en/dql-doctrine-query-language:group-by,-having-clauses) in the Doctrine documentation for more info.