# Using comparison as alias in select for Doctrine2

Tags: mysql, doctrine, doctrine-orm

Trying to do this in Doctrine2:

```
...->createQuery('SELECT m.id, (m.status != 1) as verified...
```

But that throws an error - if I take parenthesis off I get another error. How do I achieve this m.status comparison?

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same problem. The comparison doesn't seem to parse correctly in DQL.

Answer (score 5):

Doctrine 2 doesn't support these comparisons in the SELECT clause (at least not up to 2.3, not sure about 2.4).

You can use a CASE expression as workaround:

```
SELECT m.id, CASE WHEN m.status != 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS verified ...
```

or:

```
SELECT m.id, CASE WHEN m.status = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS verified ...
```

If you need `verified` for an ORDER BY clause (or something like that), but don't actually need it in the result, you can use the HIDDEN expression:

```
SELECT m.id, CASE WHEN m.status = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END AS HIDDEN verified ...
```

A completely different solution is to write a [custom DQL function](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/latest/reference/dql-doctrine-query-language.html#adding-your-own-functions-to-the-dql-language).

Answer (score -1):

You can use the solution proposed here: [Cumulative DQL with Doctrine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513384/cumulative-dql-with-doctrine)

When working with entities, keep in mind that adding selects will make the query return an array for each result:

```
$res = $em->createQueryBuilder()
  ->from('BlogPost', 'p')
  ->select('p')
  ->addSelect('(2+3) AS dummy')
  ->getQuery()->getResult();
```

Iterating over $res will return an array:

```
foreach($res as $mixed){
  echo get_class($mixed[0]); //$mixed[0] contains the BlogPost
  echo $mixed['dummy']; //displays the dummy result (5)
}
```

Comment: Using addSelect() is the same as putting it directly in the original select() or createQuery(). The problem is with the comparison not parsing correctly, not with adding more select parts.

Answer (score -2):

check this out: [13.2.4. Using Expr* classes to create conditionals](http://www.doctrine-project.org/docs/orm/2.0/en/reference/query-builder.html#the-expr-class)

using Expression methods you could do something like:

```
$qb = $this->entityManager->createQueryBuilder();

$query = $qb->select('m.id')
            ->from('Entities\MyEntity', 'm')
            /*neq() is the "not equal" comparison function*/
            ->where($qb->expr()->neq('m.status', $someValue)),
            ->getQuery();
```

Comment: I'm not trying to filter the data with a condition - just want my result set to have a boolean alias based on the result returned.  This is very straightforward in sql or doctrine 1 but doctrine2..

Comment: It's easy to add conditions in where. My problem and that of the original poster is to use this expression in the select part. For example, are this comment's author and the question's author the same? Put the result into "is_original_poster".